# systemctl error on running systemctl start <application>

Tags: service, systemd, systemctl

faced this error while running my application using systemctl where is actually the problem with?systemctl error on running systemctl start ?

```
Jul 27 16:20:36 nikhil-Lenovo-ideapad-300-15ISK systemd[1]: Started <application> Web Interface.
Jul 27 16:20:36 nikhil-Lenovo-ideapad-300-15ISK systemd[1]: <application>.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Jul 27 16:20:36 nikhil-Lenovo-ideapad-300-15ISK systemd[1]: <application>.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jul 27 16:20:36 nikhil-Lenovo-ideapad-300-15ISK systemd[1]: <application>.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 27 16:20:36 nikhil-Lenovo-ideapad-300-15ISK systemd[1]: <application>.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Jul 27 16:20:36 nikhil-Lenovo-ideapad-300-15ISK systemd[1]: Stopped <application> Web Interface.
Jul 27 16:20:36 nikhil-Lenovo-ideapad-300-15ISK systemd[1]: Started <application> Web Interface.
Jul 27 16:20:36 nikhil-Lenovo-ideapad-300-15ISK systemd[1]: <application>.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Jul 27 16:20:36 nikhil-Lenovo-ideapad-300-15ISK systemd[1]: <application>.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jul 27 16:20:36 nikhil-Lenovo-ideapad-300-15ISK systemd[1]: <application>.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 27 16:20:37 nikhil-Lenovo-ideapad-300-15ISK systemd[1]: <application>.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Jul 27 16:20:37 nikhil-Lenovo-ideapad-300-15ISK systemd[1]: Stopped <application> Web Interface.
Jul 27 16:20:37 nikhil-Lenovo-ideapad-300-15ISK systemd[1]: Started <application> Web Interface.
Jul 27 16:20:37 nikhil-Lenovo-ideapad-300-15ISK systemd[1]: <application>.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Jul 27 16:20:37 nikhil-Lenovo-ideapad-300-15ISK systemd[1]: <application>.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jul 27 16:20:37 nikhil-Lenovo-ideapad-300-15ISK systemd[1]: <application>.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 27 16:20:37 nikhil-Lenovo-ideapad-300-15ISK systemd[1]: <application>.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Jul 27 16:20:37 nikhil-Lenovo-ideapad-300-15ISK systemd[1]: Stopped <application> Web Interface.
Jul 27 16:20:37 nikhil-Lenovo-ideapad-300-15ISK systemd[1]: Started <application> Web Interface.
Jul 27 16:20:37 nikhil-Lenovo-ideapad-300-15ISK systemd[1]: <application>.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Jul 27 16:20:37 nikhil-Lenovo-ideapad-300-15ISK systemd[1]: <application>.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jul 27 16:20:37 nikhil-Lenovo-ideapad-300-15ISK systemd[1]: <application>.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 27 16:20:37 nikhil-Lenovo-ideapad-300-15ISK systemd[1]: <application>.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Jul 27 16:20:37 nikhil-Lenovo-ideapad-300-15ISK systemd[1]: Stopped <application> Web Interface.
Jul 27 16:20:37 nikhil-Lenovo-ideapad-300-15ISK systemd[1]: Started <application> Web Interface.
Jul 27 16:20:37 nikhil-Lenovo-ideapad-300-15ISK systemd[1]: <application>.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Jul 27 16:20:37 nikhil-Lenovo-ideapad-300-15ISK systemd[1]: <application>.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jul 27 16:20:37 nikhil-Lenovo-ideapad-300-15ISK systemd[1]: <application>.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 27 16:20:37 nikhil-Lenovo-ideapad-300-15ISK systemd[1]: <application>.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Jul 27 16:20:37 nikhil-Lenovo-ideapad-300-15ISK systemd[1]: Stopped <application> Web Interface.
Jul 27 16:20:37 nikhil-Lenovo-ideapad-300-15ISK systemd[1]: <application>.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Jul 27 16:20:37 nikhil-Lenovo-ideapad-300-15ISK systemd[1]: Failed to start <application> Web Interface.
```

Comment: According to the log, the application is exiting prematurely. 

That means that something is wrong with your app, and not systemctl

Comment: Try logging  from the application. If it's a web interface, it's possible that it needs a certain port, in which case I have a solution

Answer (score 0):

The service unit file should set a RestartSec, most developers forget about that.

```
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=3
```

Answer (score 0):

You should find the application.service

```
locate application.service
```

And checking if the file, which ExecStart starts, exists.

Perhaps you have upgraded the system and the configuration files are the old files, you requires commit.

Gentoo does it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use locate utility to find application.service.

Execute:

```
systemctl status application.service
```

Which shows status + path to static

Could share the content of application.service? 
Are you able to run application using cmd from `ExecStart=`?

Sufficient privileges could also be an issue. Check the directives `User=` and `Group=` in the `[Service]` section of the unit file.